# How to make flex navbar menu change to burger menu when i shrink my desktop screen size? (or change to mobile size)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**HOW TO MAKE THIS ONE**

I want to make a responsive website, I have tried to make this one many times but my code still doesnt work, when my dekstop browser  was shrink, the button cannot be clicked, but when my desktop was fullsize the button can be clicked.

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <i class="fas fa-bars burger-menu" id="burgerMenu"></i>
      <h1>Coffee Shop</h1>
      <div class="nav-menu">
        <button id="buttonHome">Home</button>
        <button id="buttonAbout">About</button>
        <button id="buttonProducts">Products</button>
        <button id="buttonContact">Contact</button>
      </div>
      <div class="search-container">
        <i class="fas fa-search search-button" id="searchButton"></i>
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    </nav>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
```

```js
// JavaScript for control burger menu
const burgerMenu = document.getElementById("burgerMenu");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navMenu.classList.toggle("show");
});
```

Comment: Where's your CSS code?